# Selenium NoSuchElementException When I Want to Detect if an Element Exist

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium in Python to detect if a sign-out button appears after log in.
I have tried these, but none of them works:

1. Using is_displayed()

```
if not driver.find_element("id","idp_SignOutButton").is_displayed():
        print("fail")
```

2. Using isEmpty()

```
if driver.find_element("id","idp_SignOutButton").isEmpty():
        print("fail")
```

They return [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56Of.png) error message.

I used chrome driver. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if the element exists or not, call `find_element()` as you are doing, but put it inside a `try/except` block.

```
from selenium.commons.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    driver.find_element("id","idp_SignOutButton")
    print("element was found")

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("element was not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and clearest way to check element existence is to use `find_elements` method. It will not throw exception in case of no element found. No need to use a `try/except{}` block etc.
`find_elements` returns a list of found matches. So, in case element exists it will return a non-empty list while in case of no element found it will return an empty list. Since in Python empty list is interpreted as a Boolean False while non-empty list is interpreted as a Boolean True your code can be as following:

```py
if not driver.find_elements("id","idp_SignOutButton"):
        print("fail")
```